# Swift Tab bar hidden but custom button still active

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a custom tab Bar where i add a button in the middle:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupMiddleButton()
}
func setupMiddleButton() {
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarItemSize.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
    var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
    menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    menuButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
    menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
    menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(menuButton)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    menuButton.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButton.frame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
 }
}
```

This bar is shown in multiple controller.

However i have a specific controller where i'd like the tab bar to be hidden.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

This code works fine and the bar is actually hidden.

However If i click in the middle (where the menuButton is added) the button action is called (a segue is performed).

How can I disable the button when hiding the Tab bar?

Thank you for the help!
--------------UPDATE Solution
I am not sure this is the best solution because i'm new to swift, but it seems to work...
in my CustomTabBarController I have added to function:

```
func hideTabBar() {
    self.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.menuButton.isHidden = true
}

func showTabBar() {
    self.tabBar.isHidden = false
    self.menuButton.isHidden = false
}
```

the whenever i need to hide/display it i call this functions.

In my case in the controller where i'd like to hide it i do so:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let tabBar = self.tabBarController as! FishBookTabBarController
    tabBar.hideTabBar()

}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
     let tabBar = self.tabBarController as! FishBookTabBarController
    tabBar.showTabBar()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your button to `self.view`, so it is not "part of" your tab bar.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.menuButton.isHidden = true
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    self.menuButton.isHidden = false
}
```

That *should* do it.

Comment: Thx for the answer.... the tab bar controller (and so the button) is a separate controller so i cannot call the menuButton in the controller where i need to hide it...i tried to instantiate the CustomTabBar but i was getting a found nil on optional value... i think i might have found a solution... i'll update my question..

Comment: Just realised you've suggested the same thing... :)